Short Story about a planet run by a plant named core
Short story written in the 50s or 60s. Sci fi about a planet that humans land on, where the planet is controlled by a plant named "the core." 5 or 6 pages long. Possibly posted in a magazine.

Is the Core a "plan," as in the question body, or a "plant," as in the title?

Is it "plant" as in vegetables, or "plant" as in some form of machinery?

is core the name of the planet?
